# In how many ways can k bishops be placed on an k×k chessboard such that no two can threaten each other?

Tags: combinatorics

Not sure how to start this solution. I thought about proving by induction with a base case of k=2. In this case there are 4 ways that 2 bishops can be placed on a 2x2 board without threatening each other. I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Maximising the number of such bishops, and counting the number of ways of doing so, is called the [Bishops problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BishopsProblem.html). That link states the solution to both parts, providing several citations for the second, none of which seem to be online. Let's find the maximum first.

Filling the top and bottom row, except for the latter's ends, achieves $2k-2$ bishops legally. We can do no better (except if $k=1$). Indeed, there are $2k-1$ top-left-to-bottom-right diagonals, none of which may hold multiple bishops; and the two single-square such diagonals threaten each other, so at least one must be unoccupied. (If $k=1$ this doesn't apply, since these corners aren't distinct; in that case the maximum allowed is $1=2k-1$.)

The second part of the problem is [this](https://oeis.org/A002465) OEIS sequence. Dudeney 1970 gives the answer as $2^{\lfloor\frac{k-3}{2}\rfloor}(2^{\lceil\frac{k-3}{2}\rceil}+1)$.

Comment: It seems like you are answering a different question than was asked? OP was counting the ways to place $k$ bishops, not finding the maximum number of bishops that could be placed.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Well-spotted, thanks; I've edited.